# Jupyter Lab build: RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install

Tags: python, node.js, npm, jupyter-lab

I installed mitosheet extension for Jupyter Lab and got "Build failed with 500, please run 'jupyter lab build' on the server for full output" error when I start Jupyter Lab.

I followed the recommendation to run "jupyter lab build" but got "RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install" error.

I'm using company internet so I guess it is a firewall problem. If so, I wonder how do solve it, like using a proxy?

Here is the log file detail:

```
[LabBuildApp] Building in C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[LabBuildApp] Node v14.16.0

[LabBuildApp] Yarn configuration loaded.
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (build:prod)
[LabBuildApp] > node C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js install --non-interactive
[LabBuildApp] yarn install v1.21.1
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error Couldn't find package "@jupyter-widgets/base@^1.1.10 || ^2 || ^3" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
Error: Couldn't find package "@types/fscreen@^1.0.1" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "ag-grid-react@^24.0.0" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "@types/react-dom@^16.9.8" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "fscreen@^1.1.0" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "ag-grid-community@^24.0.0" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "@types/react@^16.9.49" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "@types/analytics-node@^3.1.3" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "react-joyride@^2.3.0" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "react-intercom@^1.0.15" required by "mitosheet@file:../extensions/mitosheet-0.1.144.tgz" on the "npm" registry.
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:38113:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:310:30)
    at C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\staging\yarn.js:323:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

[LabBuildApp] npm dependencies failed to install
[LabBuildApp] Traceback (most recent call last):

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
    yield

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 138, in start
    raise e

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 134, in start
    build(name=self.name, version=self.version,

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 459, in build
    return handler.build(name=name, version=version, static_url=static_url,

[LabBuildApp]   File "C:\Users\r051122\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\commands.py", line 652, in build
    raise RuntimeError(msg)

[LabBuildApp] RuntimeError: npm dependencies failed to install

[LabBuildApp] Exiting application: JupyterLab
```

Comment: it looks to be a network problem, do you have any firewalls or restrictions that could possible be blocking you?

Comment: Yes I have company firewall but also have a proxy to bypass it. Just want to know how to set the proxy.